# CSS: How to keep the distance between a custom popover and the control that is used to open it even if I change the size of the container

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, sass

I'm trying to create a sort of popover that change its position depending if it is displayed on a mobile device or desktop.

I almost managed to do it, but I can't make it re-usable because if I change the size of the container, the popover wont show in the desired place.

Here's the html:

```
<div class="button-cont">
    <div class="input-group mb-3 button-container">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
        <div class="input-group-append button-calendar" (click)="show()">
            <span class="input-group-text">.00</span>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-tooltip" #tooltip>
            Hello
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button-cont {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}



.button-container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 30rem;
}

.button-calendar {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.custom-tooltip {
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: white;
  width: 5rem;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 8px;
  left: 26rem;
  bottom: -93px;
  opacity: 0;

  @media(max-width: 600px) { 
     margin-left: auto; 
     margin-right: auto; 
     bottom: -86px;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translateX(-50%)
  } 

}


.show-tooltip {
  opacity: 1
}
```

And the little Angular code I use to open the popover:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-ngx-bootstrap",
  templateUrl: "./ngx-bootstrap.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./ngx-bootstrap.component.scss"]
})
export class NgxBootstrapComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("tooltip") tooltip: ElementRef;
  isOpen = false;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  show() {
    if (!this.isOpen) {
      this.tooltip.nativeElement.classList.add("show-tooltip");
    } else {
      this.tooltip.nativeElement.classList.remove("show-tooltip");
    }
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }
}
```

I know the component doesn't look like the desired result, **but it is the position what I'm interested at the moment**, this is how it should be **positioned**

[image]

This is what I need:

1) For mobile(there's already a media query for that) it should be displayed below the input group and centered horizontally

2) For the desktop version it should be displayed below the button (calendar) and to the right with a little gap.

As I mentioned it kinda works, but if I change the size of the `input-group` the popover is no longer position correctly.

[Here's a demo in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-popover-custom)

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace the `left` CSS attribute for the tooltip to `right` instead, this way it will be moved with its `input-group` container boundary:

```
.custom-tooltip {
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: white;
  width: 5rem;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 8px;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: -93px;
  opacity: 0;
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks ROOT, may I ask how you determined that -15px would be right no matter the width of the group?

Comment: since you need the tooltip to be aligned to the right you should use `right`, `left` CSS attribute will require you to do calculation to measure the with of the parent which is set using `EM` unit. you can get the with of parent using `calc()` CSS function but having right attribute is more clean.

Comment: OK, but how do you came by that number(-15px)? Devtools, trail & error?

Comment: @eddy, I used devtool,  trail & error as you mentioned, I mainly looked for what you want it to look without changing `input-group` width.

Comment: in stackblitz worked, but now that I moved into my page it doesn't because the dimensions of the input-group changed. Is there any way to set the position but taking into account the size of that container?

Comment: do you have reproducible issue link on a website? please share it and I will do my best to fix it.